# Any python library with which we can add volume keyframes for an audio file?

Tags: audio, keyframe

Does anyone know any python library with which we can add volume keyframes (timestamps to insert key, and angle of it) for an audio file, similar to the one in Adobe premiere?

Or any way with which we can achieve this effect programatically?